# How to change register link url in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change url of register present in top menu but I am unable to find it. Link is rendered in topmenu.phtml which is calling

```
$this->getHtml('level-top em-menu-link');
```

I found getHtml method in magento base class but it is calling loadTemplate and rendering it. Where is the link stored actually ?

I even tried adding it to local.xml

```
    <default>

    <!-- Removes 'Log In' link - Default position: 60 -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/data/getRegisterUrl"></url></action>
    </reference>

</default>
```

but nothing happened. I can see a function named getRegisterUrl in customer/helper/data.php but even after making changes there it is still pointing to same url.

Comment: check your local.xml file location `app/design/frontend/package/theme/layout/local.xml` and modify there.

Comment: I tried it already. I have updated my question, please have a look. @QaisarSatti

Answer (score 1):

You can change in layout file (`customer.xml`) at location `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/customer.xml`

```
<default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title before_text" module="customer"><label>'Reg'ister</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position><li/><a/></action>
        </reference>

    </default>
```

Comment: That part is already commented in the layout file

Comment: in customer.xml file? have you used RWD theme or any custom theme?

Comment: Its a custom theme.

Comment: So please open comment and change register label and check affect in top menu or not

Comment: I think it is called in base layout file app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\customer.xml

Comment: Its not even in base layout file.  I can add links using cutomer layout file but I need to delete the default 'Register' link.